# Subtract one month from mm/yy in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I subtract one month from `mm/yy` in SQL?

For an example from `02/23` to `01/23`.

Comment: tag your database name

Comment: this sounds like the month and year are stored in a string-like datatype or what is the datatype of the column?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: datatype is navchar

Comment: Do you want to convert a text value in mm/yy format to a new text value after performing a subtraction of 1 month? Could you please show some SQL (even if it doesn’t work)?

Comment: What does `mm/yy` mean?  Dates have no format to begin with. SQL Server doesn't have a way to store months, only full dates.

Comment: its a navchar column

Comment: @YossiBondasd don't use nvarchar, and even if you do, don't use *that* format. For starters, two-digit years are *THE MOST* famous bug in computing history. Don't repeat it. `mm/yyyy` can't be sorted in chronological order either, which means you can't perform range queries, or search for dates before/after a specific month

Comment: In SQL Server, [this will work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ea3b1390e19569ea7201f60d4d088a1a)

Comment: @YossiBondasd where did this string come from? Why was it created? A common way when dealing with dates is to use a Calendar table with eg 20 years of dates and extra fields for the year, month, day of month, text labels like Year-Month etc. Instead of storing strings and trying to convert them back to dates, you could store a proper date, join with the Calendar table and perform any calculations you want

Comment: @Arulkumar, strangely enough not for January 01/23 -> 12/22 and of course 3/30 -> 2/30 is not good at all

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No, [01/23 -> 12/22](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=714f633fcae55eef1c88877d7e1cad26) and [3/30 -> 2/30](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3db1e8cd1718eab0388cc7af71891271)

Comment: @Arulkumar Yes and that is wrong, also 01/01 -> error

Comment: 10/11, is that October 11th, or 10 November?

Comment: @jarlh your comment made me re-read the question and the title says mm/yy and if that is the case your question becomes, is 10/11 October 2011 or October 1911 or.... **OP**, what is your date format, is it dd/mm or mm/yy or....?

Answer (score 2):

Since your date format is not the recommended one. But for your scenario, you can use the following query to get your expected result.

Using `DATEFROMPARTS()` and string functions you can construct as a date and the `DATEADD(MONTH, -1, date)` will help to subtract one month.

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (DateVal VARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO @TestTable (DateVal) VALUES ('02/23'), ('01/23'), ('03/30');

SELECT DateVal,
       RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT(DateVal, 2), LEFT(DateVal, 2), '01')), 3), 5) AS Result
FROM @TestTable
```

Result:

```
DateVal     Result
----------------------
02/23       01/23
01/23       12/22
03/30       02/30
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=883c31351ff20fa8dd4b70e1ce0c7330)

Comment: @YossiBondasd If the answer is helpful, can you please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `convert()` to get a valid date, then `dateadd()` to subtract 1 month and finally `format()` to get the date in the string format:

```
select
  format(dateadd(month, -1, convert(date, concat('01/', datecolumnname), 3)), 'MM/yy')
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8abed97f5f62d5c67498e33052916b24).

Answer (score 0):

This comes with a warning is super ugly but if you want string previous month then string again, maybe convert to date do the dateadd then back to string, horrid!

```
with cte_d
as
(select '01/23' as stringdate
 union
 select '12/17' as stringdate
)

select stringdate
       ,cast(Month(dateadd(month,-1,cast(right(stringdate,2) 
         + left(stringdate,2) + '01' as date))) as nvarchar(2))
        +'/'+
         right(cast(Year(dateadd(month,-1,cast(right(stringdate,2) 
         + left(stringdate,2) + '01' as date))) as nvarchar(4)),2) as [NewDate]
from cte_d
```